# Find an item in a dict whose values are lists

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary

I have a dict that I fill from an excel sheet. Then, I want to know if a string exists in the dict's values. The value of each key is a list.

```
import xlrd
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Inputs_UNF_newForm.xlsx')
p=wb.sheet_by_name('Products')

def isProduct(look_for):
    Product = {}
    Keep = []

    (start,end)= rowMatrix("Products")
    number_of_columns=p.ncols
    for row in range(start,end):
        key = str(p.cell(row,0).value)
        Keep=[]
        for col in range(1,number_of_columns):
            value  = str((p.cell(row,col).value))
            if value !="":
                Keep.append(value)
        Product[key] = Keep
    print(Product)
    for value in Product.values(): #Doesn't work :(
        if look_for == value:
            return "yey"
    return "nop"
```

My questions are:
  - Is there a way for the values to be just values and not a list of values?
  - The function returns "nop" even if the string I'm looking for does exist in one of the lists, why ?

Thanks!

Comment: I just did, thank you for your remark!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the `in` operator:

```
if look_for in value:
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Python's `in` operator:

```
In [1]: values = ['one', 'two', 'three']
In [2]: 'one' in values
Out[2]: True
In [3]: 'someone' in values
Out[3]: False
```

**Update for PM_2Ring's comment:** The following code checks whether a string is a substring of any value in a list:

```
In [8]: a = lambda s, v: bool(len([ss for ss in v if s in ss]))
In [9]: a('one', values)
Out[9]: True
In [10]: a('someone', values)
Out[10]: False
In [11]: a('ree', values) #PM 2Ring comment
Out[11]: True
In [12]: a('Tree', values)
Out[12]: False
In [13]: a('tree', values)
Out[13]: False
```

Read more about list comprehensions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: You might like to mention in your answer that this only returns `True` for an exact match. Eg, `'ree' in values` returns `False`.